# DateTime entries without timezone in Magnolia CMS Dialog

Tags: java, datetime, magnolia

I'm having issues with my dialogs' DateTime entries, using the [`Date field`](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Date+field).

Only because **Magnolia CMS** tries to calculate relevant date-time to display according to your *local* `TimeZone` (vs the `TimeZone` it was entered in). By the way, that calculation is black magic (done using vaadin in their proprietary implementation I believe).

Anyhow, I wonder is there is a way to `disable` that `TimeZone` feature.

Many events are only "physical" events (they can't be attended online), so there is no point in displaying them according to other TimeZones anyway.

Example of issue this `TimeZone` feature has: [jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MGNLUI-4014](https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MGNLUI-4014) and [Magnolia CMS DateFieldDefinition issue with Daylight saving time change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40090952/magnolia-cms-datefielddefinition-issue-with-daylight-saving-time-change)

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is point of showing them in local timezones when you have distributed teams working in different timezones.

Anyway the issue you mention is scheduled to be fixed rather soon (AFAIK) and it will not affect anyone until next daylight saving change which is still couple months.

But to answer your question: **If you don't want Magnolia to calculate the time zone for you, you can just set it for your user directly in user settings** and then that timezone will be always used for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for (the 2nd part of) your answer Jan. I will try setting the timezone via user settings to see how it behaves. I have to say that the first part of your answer is completely unrelated: c.f. whether users have (or not) distributed teams. This is very opinionated & has nothing to do on StackOverflow (c.f. the forum guidelines).

Comment: You're welcome. The first part of the answer was explaining part of your original question where you claimed that there is no point for calculating timezones and displaying events in local time in first place. Since you have made wrong assumption about it, it seemed prudent to expect other even less experienced users to make same wrong assumption, hence the explanation. And to be honest I don't see anything opinionated about it, just relating reasoning made when deciding to implement it. Anyway if you felt so strongly about that part of the answer, you could have removed it while editing it.;)

Comment: Hi @Jan your answer helps with setting the time zone per user, but I wonder if there is a way to set it for all users at once with some attribute in a global config file?

Comment: Well, as per documentation - https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/6.2/Administration/Locale/Time-zone.html Magnolia sets default time zone using java.util.TimeZone, in turn, TimeZone reads it's value from OS. So set the OS where server run's to what timezone you want and you will have default value for all your users what you want.

Comment: @Jan good idea, I will do that, thanks!